# In nextJS 13.4 I want to filter countries and fetch filtered country

Tags: typescript, url, next.js

I have little problem. in nextJS I want to fetch countries but i cannot update api endpoint. I cant use useState. I also have search input in another component.

this is filtering:

```
const router = useRouter();

  const handleSearch = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (country == "") {
      alert("Fill in");
    }
    updateSearchParams(country.toLowerCase());
  };

  const updateSearchParams = (country: string) => {
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    console.log(searchParams);
    if (country) {
      searchParams.set("name", country);
    } else {
      searchParams.delete("name");
    }

    const newPathname = `${
      window.location.pathname
    }/name/${searchParams.toString()}`;

    router.push(newPathname);
  };
```

and this is fetchData

```
export const getData = async (filters: FilterProps) => {
    const { country } = filters
    console.log(country);
    const url = await fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/${country}`);
    return url.json()
};
```

I tried this in search CountryFilter.tsx but when I click on submit url becomes weird : http://name/name=asdad

Comment: What filtering or fetching is the code you have shared doing? Can you [edit] to include a more relevant [mcve] of the code you are working with?